# UWSGI connection refused from urllib2, but only if UWSGI is running as a service

Tags: python, ubuntu, uwsgi

I'm deploying a flask application via uwsgi and nginx on a pretty vanially ubuntu 13.04 install. One of the things I need to do is to post data to the server from a raspberry pi, which I am doing using urllib2.

If I run uwsgi by manually running uwsgi --ini file, everything works swimmingly.

If I run uwsgi by doing sudo service uwsgi start, I can access the user facing stuff correctly from my web browser, but the raspberry pi python app gets an HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

My uwsgi init script:
description "uWSGI"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

respawn

exec uwsgi --ini /path/to/file.ini

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably a problem with permissions. Maybe you need to set the user and group in the init file to the same as on your command line?